# Rails / jQuery: How to check for parameters

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got the following script that gets executed via AJAX in Rails and uses the ERB Template:

**Problem**
*It appears that only the first specified option (unchecking) works for switches and checkboxes works, the part inside the else statements does not work!*

```
<% if params[:type] == "switch" %>
    var obj = $('.<%= params[:name] %> a:not(.label) #myonoffswitch:checkbox');
    <% if params[params[:name]] %> // WORKS
        $('.<%= params[:name] %> a:not(.label)').attr("href", "/update?name=abc&abc=true&type=switch"); // Changes link to check on next click
        obj.prop('checked', false); // Unchecks switch
    <% else %> // DOES NOT WORK
        $('.<%= params[:name] %> a:not(.label)').attr("href", "/update?name=abc&abc=false&type=switch"); // Changes link to uncheck on next click
        obj.prop('checked', true); // Checks switch
    <% end %>
<% elsif params[:type] == "checkbox" %>
    <% if params[params[:name]] %> // WORKS
        $('.<%= params[:name] %> a:not(.label)').remove(); // Removes checked checkbox
        $('.<%= params[:name] %>').prepend("<a data-remote='true' href='/update?name=<%= params[:name] %>&amp;<%= params[:name] %>=true&amp;type=checkbox'><i class='icon ion-android-checkbox-outline-blank' tabindex='0'></i></a>"); // Changes link to check on next click & Adds unchecked checkbox
    <% else %> // DOES NOT WORK
        $('.<%= params[:name] %> a:not(.label)').remove(); // Removes unchecked checkbox
        $('.<%= params[:name] %>').prepend("<a data-remote='true' href='/update?name=<%= params[:name] %>&amp;<%= params[:name] %>=false&amp;type=checkbox'><i class='icon ion-android-checkbox' tabindex='0'></i></a>"); // Changes link to uncheck on next click & Adds checked checkbox
    <% end %>
    $('.<%= params[:name] %> a:not(.label) i').focus(); // Focuses on checkbox
<% end %>
```

**DOM**

```
      <div class="name flex">
        <a data-remote="true" href="/update?name=abc&amp;abc=false&amp;type=switch"><div class="onoffswitch">
          <input checked="" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" name="onoffswitch" type="checkbox">
          <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch"></label>
        </div>
        </a>
        <div class="label">
          <a class="abc label" data-remote="true" href="/update?name=abc&amp;abc=false&amp;type=switch">ABC
          </a>
          <p class="abc labeltext">Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="name1 flex"><a data-remote="true" href="/update?name=name1&amp;name1=true&amp;type=checkbox">
        <i class="icon ion-android-checkbox-outline-blank" tabindex="0"></i></a>

        <div class="label">
          <a class="abc label" data-remote="true" href="/update?name=name1&amp;name1=false&amp;type=checkbox">ABC
          </a>
          <p class="abc labeltext">Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

However, I noticed that only if a checkbox or a switch is checked it gets unchecked, and if it is unchecked it will not change it's appearance (the DOM).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please add a comment to the code block above which works and explain the desired outcome? Also this line is not clear `option (unchecking) works for switches and checkboxes works`. What is the value of `params[:name]`?

Comment: I commented the given code extensively. As you can now see, only if the process of unchecking either switch or checkbox works. `params[:name]` is equals to the attribute (`abc`) I want to update. So if `params[:name] = "abc"` -> `params[params[:name]] = # value of abc -> true / false`

Comment: Have you tried printing params[params[:name]] using puts before the if condition? The result of `if params[params[:name]]` will always be boolean true as your if condition checks for whether or not the variable is present. So change the condition to `if params[params[:name]] == "false"`.

Comment: I put that line into my code: `$('body').append('<p><%= params[params[:name]] %></p>');` and I get the appropriate value ( `true` / `false` ) Interestingly enough though, the executed JS does not contain the actions that should get executed after I checked whether the value is `true` or `false`. I also tried to check specificly for `if params[params[:name]] == true` and `elsif params[params[:name]] == false` - it does not work either.

Comment: it is `if params[params[:name]] == "false"` and **not `if params[params[:name]] == false`**, as everything is a string in the url.

Comment: You are my hero of today, thank you! Such an annoying mistake and yet so obvious. Write a reply and I will mark it as the aswer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `if params[params[:name]]` will always be **boolean true** as your if condition checks for **whether or not the variable is present**.

So change the condition to `if params[params[:name]] == "false"`, as this will check for the value present in `params[params[:name]]`.

Everything present in the URL is a string and so you had the confusion.